# Is this proper jQuery syntax?

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

It's as simple as that, does this line of jQuery use proper syntax?

```
$(this.parentNode img:not(:last)).toggle();
```

Comment: No it does not use proper syntax

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted?  He just wanted to know how to properly write the code.

Comment: I could write "Is `$(something.that(kinda, $looks("jQuery")ish), but.is(nowhere("close")))` valid?"  Or any of 2^50000 variants of it.  Do you *really* want to sit there for every one and say "yes, this one's valid.  no, that one's not"?  Or would you want people to at least learn the very, very, *very* basics of JS and be able to answer the question themselves?

Comment: -1 There is no such things as jQuery syntax.

Comment: I was simply wondering because I saw here http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parentnode-using-jquery that the first part would work in code, and I saw in the examples section of here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp that the second part might work, and the :not(:last) would work according to this, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp and I knew the action would work, so I was just testing to see that it would all work in conjunction. jQuery has a syntax involving js, but it's a lot like the English language in that it's extremely confusing to understand.

Comment: w3schools is not a good place to learn why ? check [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/), and also why don't you use the great official documentation of jQuery at first place ?

Comment: Please use proper grammar, when you're arguing against the person asking the question, so that I won't have to delete your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @Ethanol722:  Hate to tell you, you can't delete comments.  All you can do is flag them, and that does nothing unless a mod or a number of 10k+ rep users agrees with you that the comments are a problem.  They're not going to delete for so-so grammar, or for disagreeing with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().find('img:not(:last)').toggle();
```

Comment: are you suggesting that there is a specific jQuery syntax ?

Comment: I realize that it could be written many ways.  This way works just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'd seen something somewhere about using .parent(), but I wasn't sure if it would work.

Comment: saying `many ways to write` implicitly implies that these ways are not out of one specific language and syntax, other then that it would be `many languages to write` a solution.

Comment: Sorry, -1 for the same reason I mentioned for Question.

Comment: It *MIGHT* work??? It **WILL NOT** work. If you guys don't see the obvious flaws in that code, you really should change careers. (+1 to Omeid)